# Error converting column to bytes using encoding UTF8

Tags: python, dask, fastparquet

I got below error when writing dask dataframe to S3. Couldn't figure out why. Does anybody know how to fix.

```
dd.from_pandas(pred, npartitions=npart).to_parquet(out_path)
```

The error is

> error.. Error converting column "team_nm" to bytes using encoding UTF8. Original error: bad argument type for built-in operation Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py", line 175, in convert
> out = array_encode_utf8(data)
> File "fastparquet/speedups.pyx", line 60, in fastparquet.speedups.array_encode_utf8
> TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

I tried to encode the "team_nm" to "latin-1" before writing to parquet but doesn't work.

```
pred['team_nm'] = pred['team_nm'].str.encode("Latin-1")
```

Tried to upgrade fastparquet from 0.4.1 to 0.7.1 but it doesn't work either

Comment: `python3.7` ? That's a bit .... old. The current version is 3.11. The error doesn't complain about UTF8, it complains about the contents of the field. Are you *sure* it contains text? If not, no encoding will work. If you google the error `bad argument type for built-in operation` you'll see it's often returned when trying to treat non-text data (eg Paths, lists) as strings.

Comment: What does `pred.dtypes` return?

Comment: object. I am sure "team_nm" is string

Answer (score 0):

Parquet assumes UTF8 encoding and no other encoding is possible, so if your text is something else, it will fail. If you encode your column yourself to bytes, you can indeed choose any encoding you like, so long as wherever you are loading is prepared to do the decoding manually too.

If you have a column of bytes (because you encoded manually), then fastparquet will generally be able to guess this *unless* your column starts with some NULL/None values. To help it along, you can use the argument `object_encoding='bytes'` (all object columns to be interpreted as bytes) or `object_encoding={'team_nm': 'bytes'}` (the one specific column if known to be bytes).